# copy constructor of 'Car' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'fuelType' has a non-trivial copy constructor

Tags: c++, struct

When I'm trying to input a struct object from the keyboard, it throw me this error:

> copy constructor of 'Car' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'fuelType' has a non-trivial copy constructor

```cpp
typedef struct Car{
    int advanceType = -1;
    std::string brand;
    std::string country;
    int year=0;
    float volume=0;
    float consumption=0;
    float cost=0;
    int count=0;
    union{
        std::string fuelType;
        std::string completeSet;
    }Car;

    Car inputCar(){
        Car result;
        std::cout << "Введите марку автомобиля: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> result.brand;
        std::cout << "Введите страну производителя: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> result.country;
        std::cout << "Введите год выпуска автомобиля: " << std::endl;
        saveInput(result.year);
        std::cout << "Введите объем двигателя автомобиля: " << std::endl;
        saveInput(result.volume);
        std::cout << "Введите потребление топлива автомобилем: " << std::endl;
        saveInput(result.consumption);
        std::cout << "Введите стоимость автомобиля: " << std::endl;
        saveInput(result.cost);
        std::cout << "Введите количество выпущенных автомобилей: " << std::endl;
        saveInput(result.count);
        std::cout << "Введите 0, если больше нет дополнительных сведений об автомобиле" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Введите 1, если хотите ввести информацию о типе топлива автомобиля" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Введите 2, если хотите ввести информацию о комплектации автомобиля" << std:: endl;
        std::cout << "Ваш выбор: " << std::endl;
        saveInput(result.advanceType);
        while(result.advanceType < 0 || result.advanceType >2 ){
            std::cout << "Введите 0, если больше нет дополнительных сведений об автомобиле" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Введите 1, если хотите ввести информацию о типе топлива автомобиля" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Введите 2, если хотите ввести информацию о комплектации автомобиля" << std:: endl;
            std::cout << "Ваш выбор: " << std::endl;
            saveInput(result.advanceType);
        }
        switch(result.advanceType){
            case NOTHING:
                break;
            case FUELTYPE:
                std::cout << "Введите тип топлива автомобиля: " << std::endl;
                std::cin >> result.fuelType;
                break;
            case COMPLETESET:
                std::cout << "Введите тип комплектации автомобиля: " << std::endl;
                std::cin >> result.completeSet;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return result;
    };
```

I don't know what this error means. May somebody help me, please?

Comment: `result.fuelType = new char[32];` makes no sense.  `result.fuelType` is a `std::string`, and one of the alternative members of a union.

Comment: I forgot to delete this, I used this in previous try

Comment: `std::cin >> result.fuelType;` makes no sense, because `result` is a union, and `result.fuelType` hasn't been constructed yet.

Comment: Careful when [shotgun debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging) as it can easily get you into a worse position.